# How to make a background slideshow for the body tag

Tags: jquery, css, plugins, background, slideshow

I created a site for someone, using certain jQuery Plugins to liven up the page however during the review they requested for the background images to rotate. I've checked online for tutorials on how to do this using jQuery however they all require me creating an extra div tag. This would have been a  great solution but the problem is creatin these extra divs on the page conflict with the plugin, and that would mean having to go tidy up a whole lot of other things. Help please? Thanks.

p.s. Code snippets would be greatly appreciated

Comment: You want the background image to rotate, how exactly? What plugins are you talking about? If they conflict we need to know which one you're using.

Comment: @KirKill Simple fadeIn/fadeOut slide show is ok. as for the plugin it's not entirely been released, it's being developed by a friend still working out one or two kinks (this clearly being one), it basically allows divs on the page to be dragged and dropped any where on the page.

Answer (score 0):

insert a div for your slideshow and a div for your site's, content in the body. The z-index css-property specifies the stack order of an element. Use it like this:

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp

```
div#slideshow {
 z-index: 1;
}

div#content {
 /* for example */
 width: 800px;
 margin: auto;

 z-index: 2;
}
```

There are hundrets of tutorials about jQuery slideshow plugins you could use. This is my favourite: http://www.slidesjs.com/

Comment: seems like this should help, ..............but the link doesn't seem to load. will keep you posted when it's sorted

Comment: The link is ok for me. Z-index is easy to understand. The z-index css-property specifies the stack order of an element. The higher the value, the higher is your element.